# Applying left indent to NSTextView

Tags: indentation, nstextview

All,

Following [this](http://www.macmod.com/articles/mactech/Vol.19/19.08/NSParagraphStyle/index.html) link I made following code:

```
void MyClass::SetStyle(long start, long end, const CTextAttr &style)
{
        paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        [paragraphStyle setHeadIndent: style.GetLeftIndent() * mm2pts / 10.0];
        [paragraphStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent: style.GetLeftIndent() * mm2pts / 10];
        NSString *str = [[m_textView textStorage] string];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: str];
        [attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paragraphStyle range: NSMakeRange( 0, [str length] ) ];
        [paragraphStyle release];
        [attrString autorelease];
}
```

However, upon running this piece of code I don't see the string in the view being repositioned to the left. Running under gdb I do see the correct string is being set in the str and attrsString pointers.

I see the posting on the SO that I need to apply some text after setting the attribute, but I already have the text paragraph and want to apply the indentation on it.

I am not really familiar with Cocoa - just starting out, so I'd like to have some explanation why the code does not work as intended.

TIA.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

Apparently all I needed to do was to issue:

```
[[m_textView textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange( 0, [str length] ) withAttributedString: attrString];
```

After that the text appears with the indentation.

Thank you all.